# Corrupt APK after the update of Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-install-apk

I had the Android Studio 2.3.3 with which I was developing an application with OpenCV that tested it in a physical terminal instead of in an emulator.
Everything worked perfect and I never had any problem.

My problem started when I accepted the update of Android Studio 3.0. As soon as I reinstalled the application from android studio everything stopped working. The phone restarted.

As soon as smartphone restarts, the launcher stops again and again, the smartphone restarts again, then the Android system stops. There is no way to do anything.
I went into safe mode and uninstalled the app, but it still did not work.

I deleted all data to leave it factory. It seems that it was something better, but as soon as I reinstall the app it fails again.
I installed another version of the ROM (Cyanogen) and went from Android 5.1.1 to Android 6.0.
As soon as I install the application, everything fails.

I made a new example project to install it, and my surprise was that it also gives the same problem, and it is only the example project generated by the android studio.

I tried to put the APKs in the SD and install with an explorer, and my surprise was even greater, the explorer scrolls well, but as soon as one of the two APKs generated with this version of Android studio is displayed in the list, the explorer crashes!!. So it is impossible to install it.

It was here when I deduced that the APKs are not correct. As soon as the explorer tries to load the APK icon it chrash.

My problem now is that I do not trust to install it on any phone anymore for fear of breaking it too, because all data is lost as it has happened to me.

Do you know what the problem may be, and how can I revert the system to leave it as it was without losing any data?

Could it be that the installation through the explorer detects that the APK is badly generated, but when installing it from Android studio it forces to write corrupt files that make the operating system become totally unstable?

I extracted this from the logs:

```
11-11 20:29:06.566 30041-30059/com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet A/libc: invalid 
address or address of corrupt block 0x7ffff passed to dlfree
11-11 20:29:06.566 30041-30059/com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet A/libc: Fatal 
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 30059 (launcher-
loader)
```

Any information you need, ask for it.
I tried to reproduce it in an emulator and it did not happen.

Excuse my English for google translate;)

**EDIT**

I have two APK: one generated with android studio 3.0 and the other generated with android studio 2.3.3.
I inspected both with root explorer, and open the Android Manifest and see this:
[image: Android Studio 2.3.3]
and in the corrupted APK:
[image: Androdi Studio 3.0]

Both are the same App

Comment: Is this issue solved or still unsolved? Can you try using Android Studio 3.5.2 and see if issue is reproduced?